# Looking for user editable dashboards for my application

Tags: open-source, data-visualization, dashboard, business-intelligence

We sell SaaS B2B application. We would like to embed dashboards to present reports for users. Reports should be editable by them - users should be able to choose a chart type, report dimensions and values. Any solutions you can recommend?

I know we could embed MS PowerBI reporting for example but we are looking for a basic solution and not a full BI stack. Something more like Pipedrive has recently introduced: https://support.pipedrive.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001930658-Insights-feature

Thank you.